# Wordpress change url from http:// to tel:

Tags: wordpress, http, tel

I've been stuck on this all day!

I'm using a custom wp_nav in Wordpress and I need to change one custom menu item from href="http://555.555.5555" to href="tel:555.555.5555". I've added a class="phone" to the menu-item and I'd like to change it using that class (since I can't add a custom id in WP).

I'd prefer it be done onLoad and not onClick. Your help is much appreciated.

The code output by Wordpress is:

```
<li id="menu-item-654" class="phone menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-654"><a href="http://555.555.5555">Call</a></li>
```

I need it to look like this using Javascript:

```
<li id="menu-item-654" class="phone menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-654"><a href="tel:555.555.5555">Call</a></li>
```

Comment: You've been stuck all day, so what have you tried? Gotta have something to show for your efforts so we can help you along.

Comment: By trying to add the `tel:555.555.555` via the backend editor just gives me a blank <a> tag. So that won't work for example.

Answer (score 3):

Granted you're comfortable with a little jQuery, load it up in WordPress and paste this into your header, or create an `add_action` for `wp_head`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

  var href_value;

  href_value = jQuery('li.phone a').attr('href');

  href_value = href_value.replace('http://','tel:');

  jQuery('li.phone a').attr('href',href_value);

});
</script>
```

Let me know if that worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use my plugin - it's simpler - plus putting jQuery directly into the header is a bit messy. http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/telephone-number-linker/