# How to create clickable telephone link with WordPress Custom Links?

Tags: wordpress, phone-number

I am using WordPress custom links and I need to create clickable links for phone numbers. I have never had a problem doing this in HTML by using the following: `<a href="tel:2065221677">(206) 522-1677</a>`. But WordPress obviously has a mind of it's own, changes code, and my link does not open with my iPhone.

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11943367/wordpress-change-url-from-http-to-tel/11944631#11944631) where someone had a similar issue and I tried the jQuery script but it doesn't work when I click on the link. I get an error: Authentication required, wanting a user name and password. I believe this code would work if it were clickable not onload. Using "phone" as a CSS class is great also.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Can you give us a link so we can see why the jQuery solution posted earlier isn't working for you.  We need to see what is being output to the browser to see where you've gone wrong. BTW - welcome to SO!

Comment: The code output by Wordpress is like this:
[<li id="menu-item-654" class="phone menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-654"><a href="http://555.555.5555">Call</a></li>]

But I need this:
[<li id="menu-item-654" class="phone menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-654"><a href="tel:555.555.5555">Call</a></li>]

Comment: The proposed solution was this:
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

  var href_value;

  href_value = jQuery('li.phone a').attr('href');

  href_value = href_value.replace('http://','tel:');

  jQuery('li.phone a').attr('href',href_value);

});
</script>

Comment: With the following instructions:
Granted you're comfortable with a little jQuery, load it up in WordPress and paste this into your header, or create an add_action for wp_head.


WordPress Custom Links only gives you these options for creating the link:

URL http://
Label Menu Item

Comment: Ah, yes I can follow the link to the other SO thread, I was talking about a link to your site to see why it isn't working.  Impossible to debug from the above I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you guys aren't suggesting changing the core or theme files. Much better to bundle this functionality into a plugin like this one http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/telephone-number-linker/