# Convert jQuery JS to onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, hyperlink

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create clickable telephone link with WordPress Custom Links?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11951302/how-to-create-clickable-telephone-link-with-wordpress-custom-links)

Hello again & thank you in advance for your help.

I need to use this jQuery javascript when a link is clicked and not onload.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

  var href_value;

  href_value = jQuery('li.phone a').attr('href');

  href_value = href_value.replace('http://','tel:');

  jQuery('li.phone a').attr('href',href_value);

});
</script>
```

I am using WordPress custom links and I need to create a clickable link for phone numbers.

I found this post: "[How to create clickable telephone link with WordPress Custom Links?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11951302/how-to-create-clickable-telephone-link-with-wordpress-custom-links)" where someone had a similar issue and I tried the jQuery script but it doesn't work when I click on the link. I get an error: Authentication required, wanting a user name and password. I believe this code would work if it were clickable not onload.

Comment: Please don't re-ask questions. If someone asks for clarification, comment and/or **edit** your question instead to add new/relevant information.

Comment: what do you want to happen when the phone number is clicked?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $('li.phone a').click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var href_value = $this.attr('href').replace('http://','tel:');
    $this.attr('href',href_value);
  })
})
```

Comment: Thank you & sorry for my misguided attempts to get help.

Comment: What I need is the following.

Comment: I am using WordPress custom links and I need to create clickable links for phone numbers. I have never had a problem doing this in HTML.   
I simply need to be able to create clickable link phone numbers that activate onclick with a smart phone. Wordpress obviously strips out the required "tel:" that is needed to dial the number.  
Thank you for the code above but it doesn't work. When clicked on my phone it tries to take me to:  
h t t p: 206.522.1677 /   
I need to be able to go to:   
h t t p: tel:206.522.1677/  
Any help is greatly appreciated!  
Thank you from a JS novice.

Comment: If you have a smart phone and you go here:
h t t p: finecolorgems.com/template1/
And click: Test phone number here. You will see my problem.

Comment: On my PC it looks like there isn't any `href` specified for the `<a>`.