# WordPress Custom Link phone number

Tags: android, iphone, wordpress, hyperlink

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create clickable telephone link with WordPress Custom Links?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11951302/how-to-create-clickable-telephone-link-with-wordpress-custom-links)

I am using a WordPress Custom Links menu and I need to create clickable links for phone numbers. I simply need to be able to create clickable link phone numbers that activate onclick with a smart phone. Wordpress obviously strips out the required "tel:" that is needed to dial the number. When the link is clicked on my phone it takes me to: h t t p: 206.522.1677 /. I need to be able to go to: h t t p: tel:206.522.1677/. If you have a smart phone and you go here:
h t t p: finecolorgems.com/template1/
And click: Test phone number here. You will see my problem.

Any advice or help is greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Do not use http:// in your telephone tag. Try using :

```
<a href="tel:+440000000000">00000 000000</a>
```

Just like it is demonstrated here : [link](http://www.simonbingham.me.uk/index.cfm/main/post/uuid/making-a-telephone-number-clickable-on-android-14)

Also, try just putting the number in plain text. iPhone and Android should pick it up as a phone number automatically. (Works for me on Android 4.0.4)